# How to pass additional params to Stripe Custom Flow?

Tags: stripe-payments, applepay

Following Stripes official tutorial to create payment form with apple pay support: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/quickstart#collect-billing-address-details

But on thank you page, i need to know: user email and stripe customer id. How i can pass these parameters to thank you page?

My code for prepare.php:

```
$productID = $request['items'][0]['id'];

$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create();

$paymentIntent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
    'customer' => $customer->id,
    'setup_future_usage' => 'off_session',
    'amount' => config('app.PRICE_TNT6WEEK') * 100, //6week program
    'currency' => 'usd',
    'automatic_payment_methods' => [
        'enabled' => true,
    ],
    'description' => $productID,
]);

$output = [
    'clientSecret' => $paymentIntent->client_secret,
];

\Log::debug(['<pre>'.print_r($request->toArray(), true).'</pre>', $productID, $output]);

return response()->json($output);
```

My checkout.js:

```
// This is your test publishable API key.
const stripe = Stripe('{{config('app.STRIPE_KEY')}}');

// The items the customer wants to buy
const items = [{ id: "{{$productName}}"}];

let elements;

initialize();
checkStatus();

document
    .querySelector("#payment-form")
    .addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit);

// Fetches a payment intent and captures the client secret
async function initialize() {
    const { clientSecret } = await fetch("{{route('prepare.product', [$slug, $slugVersion])}}", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify({ items }),
    }).then((r) => r.json());

    elements = stripe.elements({ clientSecret });

    const paymentElementOptions = {
        layout: "tabs",
    };

    const paymentElement = elements.create("payment", paymentElementOptions);
    paymentElement.mount("#payment-element");

    // Create and mount the Address Element in billing mode
    const addressElement = elements.create("address", {
        mode: "billing",
        defaultValues: {
            name: 'Your Full Name...',
            address: {
                line1: 'Address...',
                city: 'City...',
                state: 'CA',
                postal_code: '',
                country: 'US',
            },
        },
        fields: {
            phone: 'always',
        },
    });
    addressElement.mount("#address-element");
}

async function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setLoading(true);
    //--- There we should make an additional ajax request with user data

    const { error } = await stripe.confirmPayment({
        elements,
        confirmParams: {
            // Make sure to change this to your payment completion page
            return_url: "{{route('upsell.show', [$slug, $slugVersion])}}",
            payment_method_data: {
                billing_details: {
                    name: document.getElementById("full_name").value,
                    email: document.getElementById("email").value,
                    phone: document.getElementById("phone").value,
                }
            },
        },
    });

    // This point will only be reached if there is an immediate error when
    // confirming the payment. Otherwise, your customer will be redirected to
    // your `return_url`. For some payment methods like iDEAL, your customer will
    // be redirected to an intermediate site first to authorize the payment, then
    // redirected to the `return_url`.
    if (error.type === "card_error" || error.type === "validation_error") {
        showMessage(error.message);
    } else {
        showMessage("An unexpected error occurred.");
    }

    setLoading(false);
}

// Fetches the payment intent status after payment submission
async function checkStatus() {
    const clientSecret = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get(
        "payment_intent_client_secret"
    );

    if (!clientSecret) {
        return;
    }

    const { paymentIntent } = await stripe.retrievePaymentIntent(clientSecret);

    switch (paymentIntent.status) {
        case "succeeded":
            showMessage("Payment succeeded!");
            break;
        case "processing":
            showMessage("Your payment is processing.");
            break;
        case "requires_payment_method":
            showMessage("Your payment was not successful, please try again.");
            break;
        default:
            showMessage("Something went wrong.");
            break;
    }
}

// ------- UI helpers -------

function showMessage(messageText) {
    const messageContainer = document.querySelector("#payment-message");

    messageContainer.classList.remove("hidden");
    messageContainer.textContent = messageText;

    setTimeout(function () {
        messageContainer.classList.add("hidden");
        messageText.textContent = "";
    }, 4000);
}

// Show a spinner on payment submission
function setLoading(isLoading) {
    if (isLoading) {
        // Disable the button and show a spinner
        document.querySelector("#submit").disabled = true;
        document.querySelector("#spinner").classList.remove("hidden");
        document.querySelector("#button-text").classList.add("hidden");
    } else {
        document.querySelector("#submit").disabled = false;
        document.querySelector("#spinner").classList.add("hidden");
        document.querySelector("#button-text").classList.remove("hidden");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After collecting billing details with either the Address Element, or supplying the `payment_method_data[billing_details]`, that information will be available on Payment Method `billing_details` ([API ref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/object#payment_method_object-billing_details)). You can get this by either retrieving the Payment Method, or by retrieving the associated Payment Intent and using [expansion](https://stripe.com/docs/expand) to include the full Payment Method object with `expand[]=payment_method`

Comment: Hello, thank you for your replay. I was able to pass billing details and phone number. But i'm not able to pass email.

Comment: You should be able to set `billing_details[email]` https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/create#create_payment_method-billing_details-email